# How to align the two views with equal width in android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Can we use single linear layout or other equivalent layout to display the view as per below image view order.

[image]

Comment: use weightSum and align text

Comment: Implemented with two different linear layout. But was seeing is it possible to get with single linear layout.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android text layout question: two textviews, side-by-side, with different layout alignments and weights](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536222/android-text-layout-question-two-textviews-side-by-side-with-different-layout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="50" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:hint="FirstName"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edi1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:hint="Enter First Name"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="50" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="LastName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edi2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:hint="Enter Last Name"/>
        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:text="Click Me"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

use the above code

Answer (score 0):

This will give you what you want and conform to [material design guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Firstname"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="Lastname"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You'll need to add `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'` to your app's build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

The below code show that how you can do this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Firstname" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Enter your firstname..." />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi" 
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Bye" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Lastname" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:hint="Enter your lastname..."  />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hello" 
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="goodbye" 
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Important**:This code only show you how to use **layout_weight** and **layout_gravity**.